# Why are 6to4 IPv6 addresses 112-Bits in length?

Tags: networking, ip, ipv6, ipv4

I was reading about 6to4 and I'm pretty confused about how the addresing works.

If you are converting an IPv4 to IPv6 using 6to4 first group will be `2002`

The next groups are determined by the IPv4 address, for example

`192.168.200.1   255.255.0.0`

So would the next 2 groups be derived from the network address of `192.168.0.0` or from the actual `192.168.200.1` ?

I am also confused about the role of the subnet id, do I include it right after the 32 bit address?

network address ->
`2002:C0A8:0000:subnetid::`

actual addres -> `2002:C0A8:C801::/48`

Help much appreciated!

Comment: I maybe misunderstood your question. But in 6to4 the prefix has 48 Bits (from a 32Bit iPv4). 16 Bits for the Subnet and 64 Bits for the host.

Comment: @SickerDude43 Is the Subnet a separate address kind of like 255.255.0.0 ? My impression was the Subnet ID is a part of the IPv6 address scheme

Comment: Kinda.. The subnet mask is a bitmask. It results that you have more than the "standard" 255 subnet adresses.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Example]

That's how an IPv6 is built. You start with the Site Prefix, follow with the Subnet ID and end with the Interface ID.

6to4 works on the prefix. There's a great example on Wikipedia:

[image: 6to4]

As you can see, from the 32Bit IPv4 a new IPv6 was constructed which has the length of 48 Bits. The two : at the end are like placeholders. After the first one you can fit in the Subnet ID[16Bit]. After the second one there is place for the Interface(or Host) ID [64Bit]. Together they equal 128 Bits, not 112. Basically the newly constructed Prefix from the second image (2002:c000:0204) is the Site Prefix in the image above. The convertion only happens on the Prefix.

Sources: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-4554/ipv6-overview-10.html

https://wikipedia.org/wiki/6to4

Comment: Please let me know if you're still confused. I'll edit the answer.